# .NET Csv Helper - Type Conversion to Double

Tags: c#, .net, import, csvhelper

In one of the columns, regarding price, the data is in a weird format when the price starts with 0.
Example : instead of 0,60 the format would be ,60.
I tried to use the CsvHelper library from .NET nuget packages, and i would receive, of course an exception when reaching a line with this kind of values, because it could not convert this to double.

This library has a documentation regarding mapping, but i could not find anything documente on how to custom config my situation :

https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/examples/configuration/class-maps/type-conversion/

Can someone give me a hint/tip for this situation ?

Here is my class setup:

```
public class Article
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ItemID { get; set; }
    public string? Barcode { get; set; }
    public double Price{ get; set; }
   
}

public class ArticleClassMap : ClassMap<Article>
{
    public ArticleClassMap()
    {
        Map(m => m.ItemID).Name("itemID");
        Map(m => m.Barcode).Name("barcode");
        Map(m => m.Price).Name("price");
    }
}
```

Here is how my file row with issues would look like :
1234|9999|    ,60

Where 1234 would be the ItemId, 9999 EAN, and ,60 would represent a price of 0,60.

Here is how the CsvReader is setup :

```
   using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.UTF8))
            {
                using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, config))

                {
                    csv.Context.RegisterClassMap<ArticleClassMap>();
                    var records = csv.GetRecords<Article>().ToList();
                    return records;
                }
            }
```

Comment: Provide example you tried, also your problem is whit CsvHelper or you used something else in your first try ?

Comment: Haven't tried something else. 
See an example above.

Answer (score 0):

I think you problem comes form ',' in your price normaly it should be '.'
One solution is custom convert commas to periods and then parse to double like this:

```
Map(m => m.ItemID).Name("itemID");
Map(m => m.Barcode).Name("barcode");
Map(m => m.Price).Convert(row =>
{
    return Double.Parse(row.Row.GetField<string>("price").Replace(',', '.'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

After hours of trying, I found a working solution in my case :

I've created a customer converter:

```
public class PriceConverter : DefaultTypeConverter
{
    public override object ConvertFromString(string text, IReaderRow row, MemberMapData memberMapData)
    {

        double result;

        //replace space with 0 in position 5 of string text, if position 5 is an empty character
        if (text.Length > 5 && text[5] == ' ')
        {
            text = text.Remove(5, 1).Insert(5, "0");
        }

        result = double.Parse(text);
        
        return result;

    }

    public override string ConvertToString(object value, IWriterRow row, MemberMapData memberMapData)
    {
        return value?.ToString();
    }
}
```

This works in the case, because in the .csv file the positions are fixed!
So, before the comma, we always have the whole value.

Then I applied it to the mapping like this :

```
 public ArticleClassMap()
    {
        Map(m => m.Price).Name("price").TypeConverter<PriceConverter>();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Set your culture. Here is an example with a culture that uses `,`.

```cs
void Main()
{
    var s = new StringBuilder();
    s.Append("itemID|barcode|price\r\n");
    s.Append("1234|9999| ,60\r\n");
    var config = new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("ru-RU"))
    {
        Delimiter = "|",
    };
    using (var reader = new StringReader(s.ToString()))
    using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, config))
    {
        csv.Context.RegisterClassMap<ArticleClassMap>();
        csv.GetRecords<Article>().ToList().Dump();
    }
}

public class Article
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ItemID { get; set; }
    public string? Barcode { get; set; }
    public double Price { get; set; }

}

public class ArticleClassMap : ClassMap<Article>
{
    public ArticleClassMap()
    {
        Map(m => m.ItemID).Name("itemID");
        Map(m => m.Barcode).Name("barcode");
        Map(m => m.Price).Name("price");
    }
}
```